# Get link title on click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a link with image. And I want to get Link Title on a click.

```
 <div class="summary">
    <form class="variations_form " method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"">
        <div class="ql-visual-attributes">
            <div class="va-pickers">
                <a class="va-picker-image" data-attribute="pa_material-and-color" title="Link Title">
                    <img class="va-image" src="img.jpg">
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Also I want to use link "data-attribute". So I try

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(".summary .variations_form .ql-visual-attributes .va-pickers a[data-attribute='pa_Attribute']").click(function(){
      var link_title=$(this).attr("title");
   });
});
```

But it doesn't work

Thanks

Comment: there are no `a` tag with `data-attribute` equal to `pa_Attribute` in your html.

Comment: The `data` attribute on your `a` element doesn't have the value you specify in the selector, hence it's not found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. your jquery selector looks way too complicated, but it's nog a big deal.
2. Your link has data-attribute with value "pa_material-and-color", but in selector you made a mistake "a[data-attribute='pa_Attribute']"

so just change selector to $(".summary .variations_form .ql-visual-attributes .va-pickers a[data-attribute='pa_material-and-color']")

Answer (score 1):

I think your are selecting wrong `data-attribute`. You can do it like following using link `class`.

```
$(".va-picker-image").click(function(){
  var link_title=$(this).attr("title");
});
```